# Swift Change navigation bar title to the title of the tableview cell that was selected

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change the title of the new navigation bar to match the tableview cell that was pressed, moving the user to the next viewcontroller.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    folderCellSelected = folderNames[indexPath.row]
}
```

Grabs the name of the cell that was selected

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = FoldersViewController.folderCellSelected
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    mindmapNames.append("Task")
    mindmapNames.append("Other Task")

}
```

And is supposed to insert the name of the cell, changing the title of the new page

But i can't figure out what to write instead of FoldersViewController.folderCellSelected

Instance member 'folderCellSelected' cannot be used on type 'FoldersViewController'

is the error i get

Comment: how do you present the next view controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function **override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)**
to send a value to the next view controller like that : 
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mytbl: UITableView!

    var foldernames = ["test","test1"]

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "next"{
            let nextViewController = segue.destination as! NextViewController
            nextViewController.myTitle = foldernames[sender as! Int]
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return foldernames.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = foldernames[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "next", sender: indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

**myTitle is a variable from NextViewController**

and then in the NextViewController do this :

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    var myTitle = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title = myTitle
    }
```

Comment: Have you set a segue? Do you create the nextviewcontroller. It was just a example the main method to use is the prepare function with this function you can send a value to the next view controller

Comment: I get a whole bunch of errors related to override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "next"{
            let nextViewController = segue.destination as! NextViewController
            nextViewController.myTitle = foldernames[sender as! Int]
        }
    } 'override' can only be specified on class members Use of undeclared type 'NextViewController' Use of unresolved identifier 'foldernames'

Comment: You do not need the `myTitle` property. `UIViewController` already has a `title` property. Just set that. This in turn is automatically used for the `navigationItem` title.